# Differences between sklearn's SimpleImputer and Imputer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, imputation

In python's `sklearn` library there exist two classes, which are doing approximately the same things:
`sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer` and `sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer`

The only difference that I found is a `"constant"` `strategy` type in `SimpeImputer`. 
Is there any other differences? When should be `Imputer` used instead of `SimpleImputer`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Imputer` class is deprecated in `0.20` and will be removed in `0.22`.  Check the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/8d7e849428a4edd16c3e2a7dc8a088f108986a17/sklearn/preprocessing/imputation.py#L64) for details. Answer to your question is then easy: you should always use `SimpleImputer`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!